# I know my table contains rows but my query returns a result of 0. How do I fix this?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

This is for a school assignment and I just cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated. My code is a mix of PHP and HTML that utilizes a form to input entries into my table in my database. The form works and entries are being entered, but when I execute the return entries function to view all the entries in my table, nothing comes back.

Here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //getting timezone data for registration timestamp
    $timezone = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

    //define username and passowrd according to what user entered
    $userFName = $_POST['fname'];
    $userLName = $_POST['lname'];
    $userCity = $_POST['city']; 
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $regDate = date(format,timestamp);

    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    //$conn2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "progAssignment2");

    //to protect mySQL injection for Security purposes
    $userFName = stripslashes($userFName);
    $userFName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userFName);      
    $userLName = stripslashes($userLName);
    $userLName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userLName);
    $userCity = stripslashes($userCity);
    $userCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userCity);    
    $userEmail = stripslashes($userEmail);
    $userEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userEmail);

    //select my desired database
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'progAssignment2');   

    //if user submits form, insert new data into table and echo success
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, city, email, reg_date) 
        VALUES ('$userFName', '$userLName', '$userCity', '$userEmail', '$regDate');";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Your form has been successfully submitted!";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    };

    //selecting data from mySQL database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

};
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Programming Assignment 3 - Isaiah Duncan</title>
</head>
<body>

<header></header>

<nav></nav>

<section>

    <h1>Insert Data Form</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">

        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="" required/><br><br>

        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lname" value="" required/><br><br>

        City:<br>
        <input type="text" name="city" value="" required/><br><br>

        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" required/><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

</section>

<section>

    <h1>Results</h1>

    <?php

    //check if (more than zero) rows are returned. if so, loop through and display
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"] . " - FirstName: " . $row["firstname"] . " - LastName: " 
                . $row["lastname"] . " - City: " . $row["city"] . " - Email: " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
        };
    }else{
        echo "0 results" . mysqli_error($conn);
    };

    ?>

    <?php echo "There are " . mysqli_num_rows($result); ?>

</section>

<?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your SELECT query is only executed if the form is submitted. Have you tried moving it down below the `};` line?

Comment: @NanaPartykar True, they might have thought that `$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'progAssignment2');` was enough, but `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");` should also have 4 arguments. Edit: You deleted the comment I was responding to. Yet, the `$db` variable doesn't do anything.

Comment: the post bit shouldn't matter except before the form is submitted. which he must have done at least once. though it should be moved i don't think it's the cause,

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I thought, I pointed wrong issue. That's why deleted. Yeah. I'm also thinking 4 parameter must be there.

Comment: @NanaPartykar You could flag to moderators to undelete your comment; I don't see anything wrong with that, that's if you want to. But yeah, your (deleted) comment was valid.

Comment: Do you want to see all of the records when you visit the page? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for your help! All of your feedback allowed me to get the code working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, I am thinking that you want to see all the records, that you previously inserted when you first visit the page. If that is the case, you will need to get your $result outside of your if statement. That if statement will only execute when you submit the form. So for example, outside of the if statement (right below it), type this:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
 $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'test');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM MyGuests";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

That should run the above query every time you visit the page. If there are any results, it should list it.

Comment: You are welcome, Isaiah. If this is your chosen answer, please remember to mark it as your best answer.

Comment: Isaiah, it looks like that my answer helped you fix your code. Would you choose this answer as your best answer? Thanks in advance.